# ImportError: No module named msg

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While i am launching roslaunch my_dynamixel_tutorial controller_manager.launch i am getting this error. It works fine till yesterday & i controlled dynamixel motors with my algorithm. But all of sudden it appears today after i run catkin_make

F File "/home/adirosgaz/catkin_ws/src/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_controllers/nodes/controller_manager.py", line 52, in 
from dynamixel_driver.dynamixel_serial_proxy import SerialProxy
File "/home/adirosgaz/catkin_ws/src/dynamixel_motor/dynamixel_driver/src/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py", line 63, in 
from dynamixel_msgs.msg import MotorState
ImportError: No module named msg

Thanks for all, for your valuable suggestions & support.

i am working with ros & dynamixel motors for past 10 months. few days back i observed dynamixel_sdk & dynamixel_workbench packages & i installed it to see what extra features in it. As a process of installing, i cloned some files form git hub, in that files some consists of same package. while i am running my code it is calling that file instead of the original file. After a long detailed observation i found this.

I resolved my issue now.

Once again thanks for all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263232/importerror:-no-module-named-msg/) by [ADIROSGAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30615/adirosgaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2017-06-06**:
Hi, add the following lines to the .bashrc file as well as update the current bash shell with it so that we don't get any build errors.
#Update ROS path to ROS environment export `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:~/<path_to_work_space_of_ros>`

and then $ source ~/.bashrc

**Comment by [ADIROSGAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30615/adirosgaz/) on 2017-06-06**:
i did that but there is no change in that error

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-06-06**:
Can you run the command `printenv | grep ROS && printenv | grep PY` in a terminal and edit the question with the results please? Also, what changed between it working and not working? Was it just a catkin_make? Why did you catkin_make it, what was changed code-wise?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
@Akhilesh: please don't advise people to change `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` by hand. It should not be necessary (`setup.(ba)sh` does this for you) and can actually make problems harder to diagnose.

**Comment by [Akhilesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28821/akhilesh/) on 2017-06-07**:
@gvdhoorn: Actually, I have faced somewhat same problem that I fixed with the same as I mentioned above. If you think it's not at all correct way to solve this, then how to solve. And what should I call it, an error or an issue in ROS.
Or am I making any mistake while installation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
Without more information I can't say anything about your problem or why changing `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` worked in that case.

With Catkin -- and any ROS version more recent than Hydro -- changing that variable manually should only be needed in very few cases.

In almost all other cases, modules ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
.. or packages not being found is caused by a workspace not having been setup correctly, missing dependency declarations in pkg manifests and / or `CMakeLists.txt`, manual editing of environment variables, incorrect workspace overlaying, forgetting to `source` the proper `setup.bash`, etc, etc. ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
.. All of those are fixable without manually changing `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-06-07**:
@ADIROSGAZ I closed this question because your latest update seems to indicate that you have found and fixed this error. If that isn't right, please comment.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
@jarvisschultz: which comment are you referring to? I only see:

> i did that but there is no change in that error

which does not make it seem as if the problem was resolved.

**Comment by [ADIROSGAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30615/adirosgaz/) on 2017-06-07**:
@gvdhoorn i found my error & i updated the same in question with how i resolved the error

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-07**:
Then I would suggest you post that as an answer and accept your own answer instead of adding the solution to the original question. That would much more clearly communicate the fact that the question is answered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for all, for your valuable suggestions & support.

i am working with ros & dynamixel motors for past 10 months. few days back i observed dynamixel_sdk & dynamixel_workbench packages & i installed it to see what extra features in it. As a process of installing, i cloned some files form git hub, in that files some consists of same package. while i am running my code it is calling that file instead of the original file. After a long detailed observation i found this.

I resolved my issue now.

Once again thanks for all.

---

Originally posted by [ADIROSGAZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30615/adirosgaz/) with karma: 31 on 2017-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0